# R using pipe instead of $ syntax

Tags: r

Syntax question. I want to filter a data set then run cor.test() without altering the original data set. I can do this in separate lines and by creating a separate data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data(trees)
df <- filter(trees, Girth >12)
cor.test(df$Girth, df$Height)
```

However I'm trying to be more efficient. I want to do the same thing in a pipe and without needing to creating a new data frame. Specifically, what is the syntax for eliminating the $ for selecting columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with()`:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(trees, Girth > 12) |> 
  with(cor.test(Girth, Height))
```

In base R:

```
subset(trees, Girth > 12) |> 
  with(cor.test(Girth, Height))
```